# syntax error: "(" unexpected when sh a file

Tags: linux, shell, command

i running a file containning such a command

comm -3 <(cut -f 1 -d' ' <./atoz |sort) <(cut -f 1 -d' '

It succeeds when it was run outside of the file.
But i get error:"file1: 1: file1:Syntax error: "(" unexpected ", when i type

sh file1 file2   and try to run the command from the file1.

The file have no any #!/bin/bash or .sh suffix since i dont have the background to solve this kind of problem..

Does somebody know how to solve it? Thanks a lot

Comment: comm -3 <(cut -f 1 -d' ' <./atoz |sort) <(cut -f 1 -d' ' <$1|sort)

Comment: sorry the command should be the above one

Comment: BTW, it's best not to give executable scripts any extension at all; `.sh` or `.bash` extensions should be used for shell libraries, intended to be sourced from other scripts rather than executed directly. Something intended to be directly executed should be marked executable (`chmod +x yourscript`) and given a shebang (`#!/usr/bin/env bash`, or similar).

Comment: I thing you are running this script `sh code.sh`. This means you are using `sh` to run the script, but the first line (`#!/bin/bash`) implies it's been written for `bash`.

On some systems `sh` and `bash` are the same, but on others they are not; and, when invoked as `sh`, `Bash` turns off some non-POSIX features. So it's important to use the right shell and the right invocation.

Use `bash code.sh` or better still, make the script executable (`chmod a+x code.sh`) and then run it directly (`./code.sh`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process substitution (`<()`) is a bash feature. It is not supported with `/bin/sh`, which guarantees only features present in the [POSIX sh specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html) (on platforms conformant with 1992-era or newer POSIX specifications; on old ones, it could be 1970s-era Bourne).

Use `bash yourscript`, or a `#!/bin/bash` shebang, to run this file.